# Github action check hanging forever

Tags: github, github-actions

## Issue

After removing an action, sync this change in master, all prs started to have this hanging job.

`test Expected Waiting for status to be reported`

[image]

I tried closing and reopening prs, triggering jobs again, nothing worked. I dont have any single reference in my github workflow files of it, neither in github actions...

Comment: It looks like the check is still required, so you maybe have to update the branch protection settings to make it not required.

Comment: Can you share your Github workflows yaml file?

Comment: @atomicfruitcake I have more than I'd like to share... The reference for this check comes from nowhere, and it's not reflected in github actios either just in checks. What it's even more weird is that creating a job with the same name just fixes it.

Comment: @PawFV I'd guess that there will be some build step within the `test` job that is getting stuck when running on GH actions. Can you start by removing each build step to find which one is hanging and potentially share just that?

Comment: @BenjaminW. That solved the issue completely thanks a lot!

Comment: @BenjaminW. edited my question with your solution and linked your profile 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the status check is set as "required" in the branch protection rules.

To disable, in the GitHub repo > Settings > Branches > Branch protection rules > Edit master > Status checks that are required > remove `test`.